# trigger on opportunity whenever the data of the field get changed in the Custommetadata, then update that field data on the related Account field

Tags: triggers, salesforce

2 Fields on Custom metaData:
Opportunity Field Name 
Account Field Name

trigger on opportunity whenever the data of the field get changed (the field that are mentioned in the Custom metadata), then update that field data on the corresponding Account field.
I tried to get Field Values from Custom metaData like `Map<Id,Object_Field_Mapping__mdt> metaData = new Map<Id,Object_Field_Mapping__mdt>([SELECT Account_Field_Name__c,Opportunity_Field_Name__c FROM Object_Field_Mapping__mdt]);`

And now the problem is I am not able to compare these value with the whole Account object so that i can update on Opportunity.....This sounds little bit confusing but this is what i have to do

Is there any way to compare CustomMetaData Field Value with Account Object..
Someone told me it can be used by Schema/sObjects but I am not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Schema like this

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> accFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

and you can access its field value like this `accFields.values()`

```
for(Schema.SObjectField field : accFields.values())
        {
            //Some Code here
        }
```

for more information about Schema Class and it's Method please check [Schema Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm)

Hope it Helps

Thanks